# dabeng's OrgChart place the main node in the center of the screen

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, orgchart

i want to make a bi-directional chart (i use for it two charts left to right and right to left directions). At the moment i got this https://codepen.io/awesomefalm/pen/MWpoaJb
And now I want to make it so that the main node is always centered on the screen (even when narrowing and expanding the chart) but dont know how can do this.

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() {
   var ds = {
     'name': 'Lao Lao',
     'className': 'middle-level',
     'children': [
       { 'name': 'Bo Miao', 'className' : 'rd-dept' },
       { 'name': 'Su Miao', 'className' : 'rd-dept',
         'children': [
           { 'name': 'Tie Hua', 'className' : 'product-dept' },
           { 'name': 'Hei Hei', 'className' : 'product-dept',
             'children': [
               { 'name': 'Pang Pang', 'className' : 'pipeline1' },
               { 'name': 'Xiang Xiang', 'className' : 'frontend1' }
             ]
            }
          ]
        },
        { 'name': 'Hong Miao', 'className' : 'rd-dept' },
        { 'name': 'Chun Miao', 'className' : 'rd-dept' }
      ]
    };

    var ocLeft = $('#leftSideChart').orgchart({
      'data' : ds,
      'direction': 'r2l',
      'parentNodeSymbol': 'fa-sitemap'
    });
    
    var ocRight = $('#rightSideChart').orgchart({
      'data' : ds,
      'direction': 'l2r',
      'parentNodeSymbol': 'fa-sitemap'
    });

  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.chart-container {
  font-family: Arial;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}
.orgchart {
  background: none;
}
div#leftSideChart {
  margin-left: 60px;
}
div#rightSideChart {
  margin-left:-182px;
}
.orgchart .node .title{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:5px;
    font-size:20px;
    height:auto;
    border-radius:4px 4px 4px 4px
    }
.orgchart .middle-level .title {
  background-color: #006699;
}
.orgchart .product-dept .title {
  background-color: #009933;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.orgchart .rd-dept .title {
  background-color: #6b5b95;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.orgchart .pipeline1 .title {
  background-color: #00ffff;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.orgchart .frontend1 .title {
  background-color: #ffa500;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.orgchart.l2r .node .title{
    transform:rotate(-90deg) translate(-30px, -28px) rotateY(180deg);
    }
.orgchart.r2l .node .title{
    transform:rotate(-90deg) translate(-30px,-28px);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/orgchart/3.1.1/css/jquery.orgchart.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/orgchart/3.1.1/js/jquery.orgchart.min.js"></script>
    <div id="leftSideChart" class="chart-container"></div>
    <div id="rightSideChart" class="chart-container"></div>
```